# Logback shows DEBUG output with root at level INFO when org.hibernate.SQL logger configured

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, logging, logback

Why would logback allow DEBUG output thru a root logger set to level INFO?

The context is a spring-boot-starter project using Hibernate. The POM names logback-classic and  logback-core at version 1.2.0.  The following config file is on its classpath (src/main/resources), sets the root logger to INFO level.

**logback-test.xml:**

```
<configuration scan="true" debug="false">
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>logs/test.log</file>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{&quot;yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX&quot;, UTC} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
  <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG" />
</configuration>
```

Plenty of INFO/WARN/ERROR messages come thru in the file during a JUnit test. But I'm surprised to see the following DEBUG output from org.hibernate.SQL, which is the ONLY package that contributes debug-level output. I thought I would have to set the root logger to level DEBUG to allow this; I figured level INFO would block it:

```
2018-09-18T13:31:02.596Z [http-nio-auto-1-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.SQL - delete from C_NOTIF_XYZ where ID=?
```

Under the covers it appears that Hibernate uses org.jboss.logging.Logger via annotations, see https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/internal/CoreLogging.java

Due to use of annotations, I'm not confident I found the exact class that creates the Delete output shown above.  I see from googling that some people suggest an interaction of logging shim classes; but I'm not sure.

Very similar SO question (so I'm not alone :) but no answer: [Using logback, debug messages are still being logged though root level is set to "Error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250627/using-logback-debug-messages-are-still-being-logged-though-root-level-is-set-to)

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the docs](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/architecture.html#effectiveLevel):

> The effective level for a given logger L, is equal to the first non-null level in its hierarchy, starting at L itself and proceeding upwards in the hierarchy towards the root logger.

So, you *can* define an effective level for a logger which overrides the root level. The behaviour you are seeing is default Logback behaviour.

If you want to disable the DEBUG logging from `org.hibernate.SQL` logger then either:

- Remove the `org.hibernate.SQL` logger configuration since this will cause the `org.hibernate.SQL` logger to assume the `root` logger level
- Assign the `org.hibernate.SQL` logger a log level other than DEBUG

Comment: Is the effective level for logger org.hibernate.SQL actually DEBUG (as set directly) or INFO (as set on root)?

Comment: In your configuration the effective level of `org.hibernate.SQL` is `DEBUG` because that level is set at a lower point in the hierarchy than the `root` level of `INFO`. There are four useful examples (in tabular form) in the [docs](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/architecture.html#effectiveLevel) which show how the effective level is determined.

Comment: I guess I'm confusing inheritance/effective level with filter/cutoff level.  I understand now that the root config sets the default effective level on all loggers.  So with effective level debug, the org.hibernate.SQL loggers are letting DEBUG and above thru.  My file appender has no filter clause, so those events appear in the output.  Is that the right way to think about this case?

Comment: Your file appender has no filter clause so it will accept whatever thelogging subsystem gives it. The logging subsystem will give it log events with Level >= INFO **and** all log events emited by `org.hibernate.sql` with level >= DEBUG.

Comment: the docs cleary show an example. if each logger in hierachy has a level defined then it must be respected otherwise effective rule calculation goes on.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line:

```
  <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG" />
```

Comment: Yes thanks I found that removing that line indeed suppresses the debug output, but would like to understand why.

Comment: The JBoss logger they're using is made to be compatible with many other logging frameworks and send them the log messages if it's not the main one being used, like for example when it's part of a library like Hibernate. In a project I work on, I added `System.setProperty("org.jboss.logging.provider", "slf4j");` on startup, and it makes the JBoss logger send the messages to whatever SLF4J implementation is being used. By all likelihood, either Spring is telling it to use logback, or it detected it automatically.

Comment: As for why it's taking that setting, and not the `root`, `root` defines the lowest priority value that it defaults to, and those messages are being sent to `org.hibernate.SQL` specifically, which has a higher priority setting.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I don't find the reference to the documentation, but I confirm this mode of operation: behavior for ancestor loggers reached through additivity, which by default is set to true, skips log level checks.
Then the log message is sent to the root logger regardless of his log level.

Comment: I didn't ask about additivity.  I don't understand this answer at all.

Comment: In your logback-test.xml configuration file set additivity to false to stop "propagation" to the root logger which, as mentioned in the answer, does not check the log level in the case of propagated logs, always going to write the message that has arrived.
This configuration will stop to write to the root logger:
...
<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG"  additivity="false">
<appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</logger>
...

Comment: this sounds like a bug.

Comment: Bug? They will give you another page of philosophical mambo-jumbo explanation of why it's not, and few random historical quotes.